# MATLAB installed but not in activities

Tags: software-installation, matlab, favorites

I am very new to Ubuntu.
I installed MATLAB 2022a Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, and I can start it from terminal window by typing matlab

The matlab binary can be found both in /usr/local/bin, and /usr/local/MATLAB2022a/bin

I would like for matlab binary to be docked in activities, and be my favorite app. How can I do that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There should be the answer you want here: https://superuser.com/questions/1282203/how-do-i-add-a-shortcut-to-the-show-applications-menu-in-ubuntu-17

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work for me. I added a desktop file based on FireFox, and I pointed the binary file to my matlab, but in the end nothing happened to my activities list.

Comment: Try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103213/how-can-i-add-an-application-to-the-gnome-application-menu